# Stuck with adding target to button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've created a UIButton and I want it to print some message when it's pressed.

So I did something like this:
In loadView()

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

A method:

```
func pressButton(button: UIButton) {

    NSLog("pressed!")

}
```

But nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Looks like you're calling the function that's in ViewController, but your target is self. if you trying to do this from another ViewController, self will need to be ViewController.

Answer (score 31):

Add the button code in your `viewDidLoad` and it will work for you:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
    NSLog("pressed!")
}
```

You don´t need to add `ViewController.pressButton` to `selector`, it´s enough with the `function name`.

**Swift 4.x version:**

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
button.backgroundColor = .gray
button.tag = 0
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)

@objc func pressButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("Button with tag: \(button.tag) clicked!")
}
```

**Swift 5.1 version:**

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
button.backgroundColor = .gray
button.tag = 100
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)

@objc func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("Button with tag: \(button.tag) clicked!")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try this in Swift3!

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func pressButton(button: UIButton) { NSLog("pressed!") }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.cartButtonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Your class name corresponds to **FirstViewController**

And your selector corresponds to the following function

```
func cartButtonHandler() {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3 use this -

```
object?.addTarget(objectWhichHasMethod, action: #selector(classWhichHasMethod.yourMethod), for: someUIControlEvents)
```

For example(from my code) -

```
self.datePicker?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(InfoTableViewCell.datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Just give a `:` after method name if you want the sender as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the `addTarget` call is in `loadView()`. Is this in your custom subview, of some kind, or the viewController?

From your selector, it's targeting a method in your `ViewController` class, but if the `target` for this action is the view itself, then it would make sense that the action is not going through.

If you declare your button in a viewController, and in `viewDidLoad` add this target as above, then the message should be printed as you're looking for. I believe you are "targetting" the wrong class with your action.

Comment: So then what calls `loadView()`? That's not a standard view controller lifecycle method. It's a standard view lifecycle method.

Comment: All the code is in a view controller that's named "ViewController". Is there a difference between calling addTarget in loadView() and viewDidLoad()?

Comment: yes, in a view controller you'd need to do it in viewDidLoad()

Comment: So I cut and pasted addTarget() into viewDidLoad(). Nothing is happening still.

Comment: how is `button` declared?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124738/discussion-between-user234159-and-bhendricks).

Answer (score 0):

```
 let cancelButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: popUpView.frame.size.width/2, y: popUpView.frame.size.height-20, width: 30, height: 30))
        cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: cancelImage)!)
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentsViewController.canceled), for:.touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the button code in `override func viewDidLoad()` method
2. Make sure your action handler tagged with @IBAction like this:

   @IBAction func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
       print("pressed!")
   }

Then it will work!